# Date string formatting in dojo or javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have my dateString in this format : `2013/05/04 00:00:00`. From this, I want to form date object in the form `yyyy/MM/dd` in javascript or in dojo. I tried using `date.format`. But it is unable to understand the format and returning me `null`. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to transform this 2013/05/04 00:00:00 to this 2013/05/04 ? or what exactly

Comment: Yes. exactly. I want from 2013/05/04 00:00:00 to 2013/05/04 , but 2013/05/04 00:00:00 is a string where as 2013/05/04 should be date

Answer (score 5):

been answered, but if you using dojo, you can do it like this

```
require(["dojo/date/locale"], function(locale){
  console.log(locale.format(new Date("2013/05/04 00:00:00"),{
    selector: "date",
    datePattern : "yyyy/MM/dd"
  }));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate using a library like the one described in [String.format for JavaScript](http://www.masterdata.se/r/string_format_for_javascript/).  It is a little more functional than simple string parsing.

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.format("yyyy/MM/dd"); // prints 2013/05/30
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVgTc/